# register device for push notification on first startup

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, push, apple-push-notifications

The very first time you start a push app, the user gets asked if he wants to allow push notifications.

the problem here is, that `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` gets called before the user made a decision, so the `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` are all disabled before the user clicks a button.

i register the device on my server for push messages in this `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method, so the very first time i get a user that disabled all notifications, although the user probably clicked "allow" a few seconds later.

the next startup this information gets updated, but as long as a user doesn't restart the app (which can take a long time in times of multitasking) i'm unable to send this person a push message.

does somebody have a tip for me? is there a better place to update my server with the user settings. is there probably a callback from the popup that appears the very frist time?

thanks for all hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't track the enabled notification types on your server. When a user disables a certain type of notification for your app, e.g. sounds, your notification can still contain a sound key, but the device won't play it.

The problem is that a user could (re-)enable any notification types for your app while it's not running, so your server wouldn't have a chance to notice the change and you wouldn't deliver notifications, even though the user expects them.

Comment: I think I understand why Apple would send that message in the first place, but could you give an idea on how to then do this properly?

Comment: i add those values to my server because i don't want so send notifications to people who have deactivated all notifications.

Comment: If the user disables notifications, the feedback service ought to tell you (and if not, I wouldn't worry about it). You could also try re-registering periodically a few times on startup (if no notifications are enabled) or when your app is foregrounded. You might not even need to re-registr; perhaps enabledRemoteNotificationTypes changes (and perhaps you can observe it using KVO if it doesn't post a notification).